# How to take value from sender onclick event

Tags: asp.net

This My Client i put in value `Eval("UserId")` and trying to get it on server

```
  <input type="button" id="Promouter" runat="server"  
        value='<%# Eval("UserId") %>' 
        onserverclick="Promoter_Onclick"> <%# Eval("FirstName") %> </input>
```

This server

```
protected void Promoter_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InfinityNightDataContext data = new InfinityNightDataContext();
    lvInvaited.DataSource = data.PartyPpls.Where(dbPartyPpls => dbPartyPpls.PartyId == 1 && dbPartyPpls.PromoterId == sender.value);
    lvInvaited.DataBind();
    lvInvaited.Visible = true;

}
```

i can see the value of sender that i need but i get it from sender i know that sender.value dosn"t work 
How can i get this value from sender

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're likely going to have to cast it to HtmlInputButton.

```
protected void Promoter_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlInputButton button = (HtmlInputButton)sender;
    int value = int.Parse(button.Value.ToString()); // or int, whatever it'll be.

    InfinityNightDataContext data = new InfinityNightDataContext();
    lvInvaited.DataSource = data.PartyPpls.Where(dbPartyPpls => dbPartyPpls.PartyId == 1 && dbPartyPpls.PromoterId == value);
    lvInvaited.DataBind();
    lvInvaited.Visible = true;

}
```

Comment: I get this error  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputButton' to type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton'.

Comment: With `HtmlInputButton` you may use `btn.Value` instead of `btn.Attributes["value"]`

Comment: @VovaPotapov you can accept correct answer. That way other visitors will know which answer is correct and you will say more valuable "Thank you" to an author. With regards.